# Как получить несколько параметров из одного select option?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Необходимо при выборе select option получить не один параметр name, а два.

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Пример:

```
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg">
   <option coin="btc" value="2013-04-28">Bitcoin</option>
   <option coin="eth" value="2015-08-07">Ethereum</option>
</select>
```

`name="date"` получаю, как получить значение `coin` и передать далее post запросом?

Данный вопрос продолжение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1286961/363391), т.к. ответ не получен, решил пойти другим путем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1: менять js-ом имя `select`. На сарваре соответсвенно будут данные вида `$_POST['date'] == ['btc'=>'2013-04-28']`

```js
$('#date-select').change(function(){
  var coin = $(this).find(':selected').data('coin');
  $(this).prop('name','date['+coin+']');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/">
  <select name="date[btc]" id="date-select" class="form-control input-lg">
     <option data-coin="btc" value="2013-04-28">Bitcoin</option>
     <option data-coin="eth" value="2015-08-07">Ethereum</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Вариант 2: пихать в `value` и название монеты и дату, используя какой-нибудь разделитель. А потом уже на сервере разбивать строку в массив через `explode` и т.д.

```
<select name="date" id="date-select" class="form-control input-lg">
 <option value="btc|2013-04-28">Bitcoin</option>
 <option value="eth|2015-08-07">Ethereum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестировать.